# Calculating $g'(0)$ given function of $f$ and $f'$ at a certain point.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBlVh.png)

I keep hitting a dead end here and I think it's because I'm solving it wrong. Can someone please look at the image question and what I have done so far myself to see if I'm doing this right and what next step I need to do.

Let  $f:R^2→R$  be a differentiable function with  $f(0,−2)=3$  and  $∇f(0,−2)=(−6,2).$

Let  $g(t):=∥∥(t,t^2,f(3t,t−2))∥∥$

What is $g'(0)$?

Here's what I did:

Let t = 0. Then, $g(0):=∥∥(0,0^2,f(3(0),(0)−2))∥∥ = ∥∥(0,0,f(0,−2))∥∥ = ∥∥(0,0,3)∥∥$

So $g(0) = 3$. I'm not quite sure if it's important to know that $g(0) = 3$ for this question.

So, now  $g'(t):=∥∥(t,t^2,f(3t,t−2))'∥∥ = ∥∥(1,2t,f'(3t,t−2))∥∥$
So  $g'(0):=∥∥(1,0,f'(0,−2))∥∥ = ∥∥(1,0,(-6,2))∥∥$.

And here's where I get stuck. I think I did $g'(0)$ part wrong and I'm not quite sure how to finish solving this question.

All help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have$$\require{cancel}g^2(t)=t^2+t^4+f^2(3t,t-2),$$and therefore$$2g(t)g'(t)=2t+4t^3+2f(3t,t-2)\bigl\langle\nabla f(3t,t-2),(3,1)\bigr\rangle.$$In particular,$$\cancel2g(0)g'(0)=\cancel2f(0,-2)\bigl\langle(-6,2),(3,1)\bigr\rangle.$$and so$$g'(0)=\frac{\cancel{f(0,-2)}\times(-16)}{\cancel{g(0)}}=-16.$$

Comment: How did you get -16? Thanks !!!

Comment: I was able to follow and get to isolating g'(0), but I don't follow on how ⟨(−6,2),(3,1)⟩ gives -16

Comment: Because $\bigl\langle(-6,2),(3,1)\bigr\rangle=(-6)\times3+2\times1=-16$.

Comment: so we take the dot/inner product of (-6,2) and (3,1)?

Comment: Yes. The notation $\bigl\langle(a,b),(c,d)\bigr\rangle$ denotes a scalar product between $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ and when nothing else is told, it is assumed that it is the dot product.

Comment: Is there another way to solve this question? Maybe using paths?

Comment: Maybe. But this is so straightforward that I don't see a reason for searching for another approach.